# How can you produce a car::influencePlot without it returning a data frame of the values it calculates?

Tags: r, r-markdown, linear-regression, outliers

I am creating a PDF using R Markdown.  As part of my linear regression analyses and checking for outlier observations, the plot that the `influencePlot` function of the `car` package (associated with the book, *An R Companion to Applied Regression*) creates is perfect, but the function also returns -- and therefore includes in my PDF -- a data frame with the hat values, Studentized residuals and Cook's distance of the identified outlier points.

```
library(car)  # the Duncan database is in this package 
influencePlot(lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan))
```

How can I include in the PDF only the plot, not the data frame that is returned?  `id=list(method="identify"))` does not work for me because I want the outlier points labeled. Nor does [2] at the end of the statement make any difference.

Comment: Try `invisible(influencePlot(lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)))`

Comment: MrFlick, put that in an answer and I will accept it.  Had not known about invisible!!